# Deleting Files on a Network Drive that are opened by another User

Tags: windows, locking, unc

I have an odd issue currently.

I have a build script that essentially will copy over some files to a directory on a networked drive and initially had an issue where some people were leaving these files open on their machines, causing my build to fail.

A solution came up to simply delete the entire file, because theyre build artifacts, but the other day the folder itself was opened and locked.

I cannot think of a solution to unlock the folder and forcefully close any open files.

Various file unlockers don't seem to work on folders our on a networked drive from my machine.

I figure people have been copying files for years and have had this issue before me, so what are some ways you can get around this file locking issue besides asking someone to close a file or folder?

General Info:

Windows Server

Windows Local Machine

Transfer via UNC Paths

Thanks!

Comment: Closing files in another process is a bad practice that's too common in Windows administration. But closing a directory should be ok. Just connect to the computer via the Action menu of compmgmt.msc, and close the directory in "System Tools\Shared Folders\Open Files".

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: [`NetFileEnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525378) lists the open file IDs, and [`NetFileClose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525377) closes a file by ID.